# Running the same SQL code against a number of tables sequentially

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a number of tables (around 40) containing snapshot data about 40 million plus vehicles. Each snapshot table is at a specific point in time (the end of the quarter) and is identical in terms of structure.

Whilst most of our analysis is against single snapshots, on occasion we need to run some analysis against all the snapshots at once. For instance, we may need to build a new table containing all the Ford Focus cars from every single snapshot.

To achieve this we currently have two options:
a) write a long, long, long batch file repeating the same code over and over again, just changing the FROM clause
[drawbacks - it takes a long time to write and changing a single line of code in one of blocks requires fiddly changes in all the other blocks]
b) use a view to union all the tables together and query that instead
 
[drawbacks - our tables are stored in separate database instances and cannot be indexed, plus the resulting view is something like 600 million records long by 125 columns wide, so is incredibly slow]

So, what I would like to find out is whether I can either use dynamic sql or put the SQL into a loop to spool through all tables. This would be something like:

```
for each *table* in TableList
INSERT INTO output_table
SELECT *table* as OriginTableName, Make, Model
FROM *table*
next *table* in TableList
```

Is this possible? This would mean that updating the original SQL when our client changes what they need (a very regular occurrence!) would be very simple and we would benefit from all the indexes we already have on the original tables.

Any pointers, suggestions or help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If you can identify your tables (e.g. a naming pattern), you could simply say:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @sql = N'';

SELECT @sql = @sql + 'INSERT output_table SELECT ''' + name + ''', Make, Model
    FROM dbo.' + QUOTENAME(name) + ';'
FROM sys.tables 
WHERE name LIKE 'pattern%';
-- or WHERE name IN ('t1', 't2', ... , 't40');

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

This assumes they're all in the `dbo` schema. If they're not, the adjustment is easy... just replace `dbo` with `' + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME([schema_id])) + '`...

Comment: Would this work across separate database instances? Fortunately all the tables do have the same naming pattern (dbo.LicStock_yyyy), but in an attempt to keep our instances below 1 TB they are split over a couple of separate databases.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used two methods:
Someone on another forum suggested making use of sp_msforeachtable and a table which contains all the table names. Their suggestion was:

```
create table dbo.OutputTable (OriginTableName nvarchar(500), RecordCount INT)
create table dbo.TableList (Name nvarchar (500))

insert dbo.TableList 
        select '[dbo].[swap]'
union   select '[dbo].[products]'
union   select '[dbo].[structures]'
union   select '[dbo].[stagingdata]'

exec sp_msforeachtable @command1 = 'INSERT INTO dbo.OutputTable SELECT ''?'',    COUNT(*)     from ?'
,@whereand = 'and syso.object_id in (select object_id(Name) from dbo.TableList)'             

select * from dbo.OutputTable
```

This works perfectly well for some queries, but seems to suffer from the fact that one cannot use a GROUP BY clause within the query (or, at least, I could not find a way to do this).

The final solution I used was to use Dynamic SQL with a lookup table containing the table names. In a very simple form, this looks like:

```
DECLARE @TableName varchar(500)
DECLARE @curTable CURSOR
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(1000)

SET @curTable = CURSOR FOR 
SELECT [Name] FROM Vehicles_LookupTables.dbo.AllStockTableList

OPEN @curTable
FETCH NEXT
FROM @curTable INTO @TableName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

SET @sql = 'SELECT ''' +@TableName + ''', Make, sum(1) as Total FROM ' + @TableName + ' GROUP BY Make'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql

FETCH NEXT
FROM @curTable INTO @TableName

END
CLOSE @curTable
DEALLOCATE @curTable
```